# How to get exactly the same point on different screen sizes?

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, uitapgesturerecognizer, screen-size

I want to call the action (go to another view) when user tap specific area of [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Oly.png) (black dots): . Image fills whole view, content mode is 'Aspect Fit'. The problem is that when I setup it on one screen size (e.g. iPhone 8) on another the 'tap area' is shifted. I've tried to solve this with button and constraints or UITapGestureRecognizer with point conversion using screen resolution (nativeBounds), but nothing helps.

Comment: What's the image resolution (width x height)?

Comment: Image itself is 918px x 657px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use constraints to match the positions of the circles with `UIButton`s.  The trick is to use the `multiplier` of the constraint to scale the buttons width/height and position to the screen size.

I'll describe how to do it for one button, and then you can repeat it for the others.  I assume the image is `657` wide by `918` high.  If I have the dimensions reversed, you'll need to substitute the actual values for the ones I have used.

1. Create a `UIView` to hold the image and buttons.  Give this view an aspect ratio constraint with `multiplier` `657:918` which is width:height. Add the `UIImageView` to this view and constrain its 4 edges to the edges of the view with `0` offsets. Give this view constraints to the left and right edges of the main view and give it a vertical constraint to place it on the screen.
2. Get the width/height of the circle in the image and the horizontal and vertical positions of the right edge and bottom edge.  For example, the topmost circle is `106 x 106` and ends at horizontal position `392` and the bottom is at `338`.
3. Set the width of the button equal to the width of the containing view with multiplier `106:657` which is width of circle:width of the image.
4. Set the height of the button equal to the height of the containing view with multiplier `106:918` which is height of circle:height of the image.
5. Set the trailing edge of the button equal to the trailing edge of the containing view with multiplier `392:657` which is end of circle:width of image.
6. Set the bottom edge of the button equal to the bottom edge of the containing view with multiplier `338:918` which is bottom of circle:height of the image.

This will allow the button to stay aligned with the circle on all devices.  Repeat steps 2 through 6 for the other circles.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an image, you can try creating your own `UIView` subclass called `BlackDotsView`.

In the `draw(_rect:)` method, you can draw the lines. To determine where the lines start and end, you need to do some maths with the view's width and height. You calculate where all the lines end and create `UIBezierPath`s and then you stroke the paths.

In the initializer of `BlackDotsView`, you can add the dots as subviews. To make them circular, just set `dotView.layer.cornerRadius` to half the dot's width. Then, you can add `UITapGestureRecognizer`s to the dot views.

You can follow the delegate pattern by creating a `BlackDotsViewDelegate` that has a method called `dotTapped(index:)`. When a dot is tapped, you would call the delegate method and pass the index of the dot.